# Perl - Nested Arrays as a Hash Value

Tags: perl

I am relatively new to Perl and I'd like to create a Hash that's value is an array with one of it's elements being another array. Something that looks like this:

```
my_hash{key} = [ele1, ele2, [arr_ele1, arr_ele2]];
```

Here's what I am doing:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @fields;
my @child_ids;
my $children;
my %spr_hash;

# skipping header
my $header = <$data>;

while(my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;

    # my file is ; deliminated
    @fields = split ";" , $line;
    @child_ids = ();
    # field 6 is a list of 0+ numbers separated by either space or ,
    $children = $fields[6];

    # if children field is not empty
    if ($children) {
        # remove any text
        $children =~ s/[a-zA-Z]//g;

        # if commas are in the field, split on comma
        # if no comma and no space, assume only 1 entry
        # else split on whitespace

        if (index($children, ",") != -1) {
            @child_ids = split "," , $children;
        } elsif(index($children, " ") != -1) {
            push @child_ids, $children;
        } else {
            @child_ids = split ' ' , $children;
        }
        print @child_ids;
        print "\n";
    }

# ASSIGN
    $spr_hash{$fields[0]} = [$fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5], @child_ids, $fields[7], $fields[8]];

 }
```

My issue is that when my input looks like this:

```
id;date;p1;owner;description;status;1, 2;sVal;xVal
```

I get the following:

```
print Dumper($spr_hash{"id"})

$VAR1 = [
      'date',
      'p1',
      'owner',
      'description',
      'status',
      '1',
      ' 2',
     'sVal',
      'xVal'
    ];
```

c1 and c2 became two separate entries, rather than 1 array entry.

How do I produce the output:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'date',
      'p1',
      'owner',
      'description',
      'status',
      [1, 2],
     'sVal',
      'xVal'
    ];
```

Comment: Your second condition is inverted: If `$children` contains a space, you don't split.

Comment: You can't get `'  c1'` etc. because your substitution removed the letters.

Comment: That was a poor example on my part Borodin. I changed them to 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm sorry to roll back your work. You should write an *MCVE*, but your question isn't all that bad and it is also essential to leave your question in a state which doesn't make nonsense of the answers and comments so far. I've restored your original version and added the adjustments to the output examples.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help with that, sorry about any confusion. Also, you answered my question in a comment below. The issue was that @child_ids was global, and the last use of it was an empty array so every entry became an empty array when I used \@child_ids. I put the declarations in the loop and my issue is resolved.

Comment: @Bill: You also had a problem with the way you were splitting that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It's unclear whether you want the behaviour that you've written in your Perl. It removes the letters from `$children` and then tries to split it, yet your required output shows `['c1', 'c2']` which cannot be achieved this way</strike>

If you really want only the digit sequences from the seventh field then it is easier to use a global regex. I would do it like this; it just replaces that field with an array reference in-place. If you want something else then please say so

Not that `$data` is a bad name for file handle, and `%spr_hash` is unnecessary as the `%` indicates a hash already

Also, don't declare all your variables at the top of the file. It makes them global, and global variables are a *Bad Thing*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;

# skipping header
<$fh>;

my %spr;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, @fields) = split /;/;
    $fields[5] = [ $fields[5] =~ /\d+/g ];
    $spr{$key} = \@fields;
 }

 print Dumper \%spr;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what you should be doing

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @fields;
my $children;
my %spr_hash;

# skipping header
my $header = <$data>;

while(my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;

    # my file is ; deliminated
    @fields = split ";" , $line;

    # Create a new version of @child_ids for each iteration of the loop
    my @child_ids = ();
    # field 6 is a list of 0+ numbers separated by either space or ,
    $children = $fields[6];

    # if children field is not empty, but can't use if ($children) as this will 
    # not allow a single 0 to be a valid input
    if (length $children) {
        # Only want digits and delimiters so strip out everything else. 
        # Always work out what you want to keep as the set of stuff you
        # want to remove is usually wrong. The original version would have 
        # kept in the string things like $, ! or é
        $children =~ s/[^ ,0-9]//g;

        # Split on comma or white space
        # Split takes a regex so you can do the split in one go
        # This assumes that you don't have data in the field like '98 ,32, 33'
        # If you do then change /[ ,]/ to /[ ,]+/
        @child_ids = split /[ ,]/, $children;
        print @child_ids;
        print "\n";
    }

    # ASSIGN
    # Note the \@child_ids this puts a reference to @child_ids in the data 
    # so that @child_ids isn't flattened, which was what was causing your 
    # original bug. Also note that this only works because you are creating a
    # new version of @child_ids with each iteration of the loop if you moved the
    # my @child_ids outside the loop then the assignment will be assigning a 
    # reference to the same variable each time through the loop and each record 
    # will end up with the last entry of field 6 from the file

    $spr_hash{$fields[0]} = [$fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4],
        $fields[5], \@child_ids, $fields[7], $fields[8]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$spr_hash{$fields[0]} = [$fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5], @child_ids, $fields[7], $fields[8]];
```

by

```
$spr_hash{$fields[0]} = [$fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5], [ @child_ids ], $fields[7], $fields[8]];
```

In Perl, lists are flattened out, so when you use `@child_ids` in your new array reference with `[   ]`, you loose the fact it is an array, its content is copied in the new gigantic array reference and that is all.

If you enclose in `[ ]` it creates a new array **reference** and you then push a reference to the array, and not its content, which should produce exactly your second example, barring other errors in logic.

Note than when `@child_ids` is empty this will add `[]` (a reference to an empty array) to `$spr_hash{$fields[0]}`. This may or may not be what you want.

Also not related to your problem, but I would advise not using arrays for this case, each item is indeed a separate elements with some semantic, so something like that may make more sense:

```
$spr_hash{$fields[0] = {
    date => $fields[1],
    whatever_is_p1 => $fields[2],
    owner => $fields[3],

etc...
}
```

Have a look at these two tutorials for further reference:

- http://www.perl101.org/arrays.html
- https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-list/

See about array slices so that it makes your construction smaller in writing.

Comment: No. `@child_ids` is (unnecessarily) global. Please test your code before posting your answers. You need either `[ @child_ids ]`, or to declare the array within the `while` loop. You have also missed the point that the OP's code doesn't split `$children` correctly in the first place.

Comment: @Borodin thanks, my point was just about the list flattening. For the rest, see my answer: "should produce exactly your second example, barring other errors in logic."